# Why can't I use the same span ids in an html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am back again, found some time to work on a text game I have been working on for quite some time. I was using javascript to manually type out a list of what the user has to choose from in the shop, depending on their class. There are more items for a Mage than the Archer or Warrior classes, so I am trying to create a div container between at least the Archer/Warrior and the Mage class, but when the span is called, only the Archer/Warrior shop Clothes and Potions come through. It seems to be a restriction on the span in sequence (any subsequent call to seems to break past the first instance in the html document). Is there a way to get this to work without having to make a whole new object?

```
<div class="OtherStuff_Container" id="o_shop" style="display: none;">
<div id="OtherStuff_Banner">
    <p>Other Stuff</p>
</div>
<div class="Shop_OtherStuff" id="Warrior_Archer's_Other" style="display: none;">
    <div id="view1">
        <p>Clothing:</p><br />
        <p>9.) Boxers: Price: $<span id="Boxers.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="Boxers.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>10.) Silk Panties: Price: $<span id="SilkPanties.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="SilkPanties.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>11.) Silk Bra: Price: $<span id="SilkBra.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="SilkBra.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>12.) G-String: Price: $<span id="GString.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="GString.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>13.) Pushup Bra: Price: $<span id="PushupBra.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="PushupBra.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>14.) Thigh Highs: Price: $<span id="ThighHighs.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="ThighHighs.AmountOf">0</span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="view1">
        <p>Potions:</p><br />
        <p>15.) Health Potion: Price: $<span id="MinorHealthPotion.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="MinorHealthPotion.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>16.) Stamina Potion: Price: $<span id="MinorStaminaPotion.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="MinorStaminaPotion.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>17.) Mana Potion: Price: $<span id="MinorManaPotion.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="MinorManaPotion.AmountOf">0</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Shop_OtherStuff1" id="Mage's_Other" style="display: none;">
    <div id="view1">
        <p>Clothing:</p><br />
        <p>10.) Boxers: Price: $<span id="Boxers.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="Boxers.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>11.) Silk Panties: Price: $<span id="SilkPanties.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="SilkPanties.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>12.) Silk Bra: Price: $<span id="SilkBra.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="SilkBra.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>13.) G-String: Price: $<span id="GString.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="GString.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>14.) Pushup Bra: Price: $<span id="PushupBra.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="PushupBra.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>15.) Thigh Highs: Price: $<span id="ThighHighs.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="ThighHighs.AmountOf">0</span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="view1">
        <p>Potions:</p><br />
        <p>16.) Health Potion: Price: $<span id="MinorHealthPotion.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="MinorHealthPotion.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>17.) Stamina Potion: Price: $<span id="MinorStaminaPotion.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="MinorStaminaPotion.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>18.) Mana Potion: Price: $<span id="MinorManaPotion.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="MinorManaPotion.AmountOf">0</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is what my html code looks like. Again, Warrior_Archer's_Other works just fine, it is the Mage's_Other that doesn't seem to want to push the data through.

Comment: `id` values have to be unique on the page. They're all added to the `document` scope

Comment: An `id` has to be unique, there must be multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: So, for my issue, it would be best to use getElementsByClassName() instead of getElementsByID()? Is that the answer to this?

Looked at that multiple elements with the same id thread, and that was one of the things I took from it... other than the "no, they have to be unique".

Comment: Yeah, multiple equal ids in the same page for any reason is bad practice. I think you can use a class here, although I wouldn't know about making games, I have only made business apps so far (or spoilers multiple classes in the same `class="class1 class2"`). Also, the reason the second one is failing is probably because it fetches the first and then it finds a second and...it explodes. Yes you can use `getElementsByClassName()` in my opinion.

Comment: Why can't people have the same social security number?

Comment: All of these suggestions/guidance's were pretty spot on. I just needed someone like Eureka to kinda point out my obvious flaw and how easy it was to fix. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To be valid HTML, the `id`s have to be unique

This is forced on us by the [definition of `id`'s](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) in HTML. Specifically:

> When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at
> least one character. The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace.
>
> The id attribute specifies its element's **unique** identifier (ID).
>
> There are **no other restrictions** on what form an ID can take; in
> particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start
> with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.
>
> An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes,
> most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using
> fragments, as a way to target an element when scripting, and as a way
> to style a specific element from CSS.

#### You can make them unique quite easily

A simple way is to prefix each id with the section id.

```
<div class="OtherStuff_Container" id="o_shop" style="display: none;">
<div id="OtherStuff_Banner">
    <p>Other Stuff</p>
</div>
<div class="Shop_OtherStuff" id="Warrior_Archer's_Other" style="display: none;">
    <div id="view1">
        <p>Clothing:</p><br />
        <p>9.) Boxers: Price: $<span id="Shop_OtherStuff.Boxers.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="Shop_OtherStuff.Boxers.AmountOf">0</span></p>
        <p>10.) Silk Panties: Price: $<span id="Shop_OtherStuff.SilkPanties.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="Shop_OtherStuff.SilkPanties.AmountOf">0</span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="view1">
       etc
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Shop_OtherStuff1" id="Mage's_Other" style="display: none;">
    <div id="view1">
        <p>Clothing:</p><br />
        <p>10.) Boxers: Price: $<span id="Shop_OtherStuff1.Boxers.Value">0</span> &emsp; Amount Left: <span id="Shop_OtherStuff1.Boxers.AmountOf">0</span></p>
```

Comment: Whelp... I am still a newb for sure... I didn't even know you could do that to the Id's like that. /sigh.

Comment: 8-). You were almost there - you already had a "." in your Id's.

Comment: I am testing this and it seems to be working for what I am needing. I will post this as the Answer after I get some things swapped around and test.

Comment: Sweet... yup, this was what I was failing to grasp.